# Ubuntu 20.04 - not able to change desktop icon - black and white

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

Desktop Image

[image: desktop image here]

I am unable to change the desktop icon. i tried using tweaks software but desktop icon is not changing in ubuntu 20.04. its always black and white icon. please help.

Comment: did you install `gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: You probably have the wrong theme

Comment: Which icons do you want to change? All of them or everything except trash and files?

Comment: @PRATAP Yes I have installed gnome-tweaks and tried changing the icon through Appearance -> Icons. Only file and trash icon in dock is changing but not the desktop icons

Comment: @SasukeUchiha - Yes I tried to change all icons available in Gnome-tweaks. only icons in docks are changing, nothing changed in desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Tweaks → Extensions → Desktop Icons* and select *Large*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it casually simply enabling dock hiding in Settings -> Appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. You must have upgraded from 18.04 like I did. The reason for this is gnome is not isntalled properly when we upgrade.

Solution is simple. Re-install gnome 3.36 (which is what officially comes with 20.04 LTS).

```
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some custom icons packs, I guess that the ones that you chose have not desktop icons implemented.

So I recommend you to try, for example, Numix: `sudo apt install numix-icon-theme` and try now to switch to it. This should change your desktop icons.

From now on, you can choose another custom icons, and if that package does not have desktop icons, you'll keep Numix ones.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gnome-shell-extensions` to change the appearance using gnome-tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Then set the Yaru theme as the default:

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8z01.png) of the correct settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was high contrast in accessibility menu. Turning it off restored it to default.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was via **Gnome Tweaks**

- **Extensions**
- switch off and on **Dash to panel**

if one does not have the **Dash to panel** extension, try the same with **Ubuntu dock**