# Desktop icons turned black

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

I'm unable to change desktop icons. One day they turned black. They don't change in tweaks. I tried to swith theme, reset appearance to default, but it didnt help. Ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1235477/739431